# Copy an array of structs using a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, memcpy

I have a structure, called `Record` that has data associated with it, and in my program I have an array of these `Record`s. The structure looks like this:

```
#define MAX_RECORDS 1024

typedef struct
{
    char    title[80];
    char    artist[80];
    int     year;
    char    genre[80];
    char    label[80];
    double  price;
} Record;

Record record_inventory[MAX_RECORDS];
```

Since the program I'm writing requires sorting different fields of `record_inventory` into a new array of `Record`, but not actually changing the data associated with the original array, I figured I would need a simple method to copy one array to another.

I looked online and found a post on stackoverflow saying to lay it out like this:

```
void copy_record(Record (*copy_to)[MAX_RECORDS], Record (*copy_from)[MAX_RECORDS])
{
    memcpy(copy_from, copy_to, sizeof *copy_from);
}
```

Now, in a sorting method, I have a function prototype like this:

```
Record* sort_by_title()
{
    Record ret[MAX_RECORDS];
    copy_record(&ret, record_inventory); // compilation error saying incorrect pointer type
    // do sorting here
    return ret;
}
```

The comment above gives me an incorrect pointer type error. But doing all of the following will not work either:

```
copy_record(&ret, &record_inventory);
copy_record(&ret, *record_inventory);
copy_record(ret, record_inventory);
copy_record(ret, &record_inventory);
copy_record(*ret, *record_inventory);
```

So how should I be copying one array of structures to another array, and returning that? Am I even returning the correct type (the type that I want)? I guess I'm just confused as to what I need to actually be passing in, and so now I'm just trying to get something to work.

Comment: Could you give the exact error you get from the compiler?

Comment: `copy_record(&ret, &record_inventory)` should work. Note that you return the address of a local array, which will refer to invalidated memory in the client code.

Comment: @MOehm That makes sense (the second part). What should I do to avoid this? Just declare it as static?

Comment: @ydobonebi The compiler error when doing `copy_record(&ret, &record_inventory);` states: `incompatible pointer types passing Record* to parameter of type Record (*)[1024]`

Comment: You could declare it as static. You could make the client code pass in a buffer to fill.You could allocate the memory on the heap and return that. You could also redesign your sorting functions by creating a list of pointers to the elements of `record_inventory` and sort indirectly. That would mean you don't have to copy the records  at all, just create a vector of pointers (to which the same allocation options as above apply).

Comment: "memcpy(from, to, size);" ? what the heck? "memcpy(dest, src, size);" is the prototype.

Comment: @PeterMiehle That might be why it is giving me weird issues then, I'll fix that.

Comment: If you copy `record_inventory` only for sorting purpose, it may be a waste of memory. The sorted array could be a array of pointers to `Record`: the datas are then only in the original array, no duplication, and the pointers are sorted according the fields you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your function declaration states that it takes pointers to pointers, for some reason. It should be:

```
void copy_record(Record *copy_to, Record *copy_from)
{
    memcpy(copy_to, copy_from, sizeof(*copy_from) * MAX_RECORDS);
}
```

Then call it just as `copy_record(ret, record_inventory);`

Comment: The original wasn't incorrect (apart from swapping over `to` and `from`), and in fact it has increased type safety as it enforces the caller to pass arrays of the right size. Your version introduces the possibility of errors as someone could pass in arrays that were not `MAX_RECORDS` in size

Comment: Also the original does not take pointers to pointers. It takes pointers to arrays.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. If goal is to make people think this code is wrong while it actually isn't - that's a way to go, I guess. It certainly got me.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy function has the correct signature, and you would call it by:

```
copy_record(&ret, &record_inventory);
```

However you got the argument to `memcpy` round the wrong way; the destination comes first. It should be:

```
memcpy(copy_to, copy_from, sizeof *copy_from);
```

---

But your `sort_by_title()` function has a design flaw. `ret` is a local array to that function. When the function returns, it will be destroyed.  If you did successfully return a pointer to it, the pointer would be dangling.

Instead you could make `sort_by_title` take an input and output parameter, and return `void`.

---

An alternative approach which avoids having to use pointer-to-array syntax would be to wrap the array in a struct:

```
struct RecordInventory
{
    Record records[MAX_RECORDS];
};
```

and then you can use objects of that type with value semantics, e.g. return by value.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful as parentheses may have a special meaning when declaring variables. `Record *x` is a pointer to a `Record`, but `Record (*x)()` is a pointer to a function that returns a `Record` as result. You are giving the compiler a hard time trying to figure out what you want from it.

Also, `Record *x` is equivalent to `Record x[]`, and  `Record *x[]` (as you are doing) is equivalent to `Record **x` (pointer to a pointer), which is different from `Record *x`, hence why your compiler is not recognizing the types.

In addition, `memcpy()` takes the destination address first, so your parameters are inverted, and you are also copying a single element from the array instead of the entire array, as [keltar pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31740060/156811).

Comment: `Record (*x)[]` is different to both `Record (*x)()` and `Record *x[]` (which he is not doing)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Probably. I'm not sure what `Record (*x)[]` means.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, It's impossible to sort an array by simply giving the array itself as an argument. Because in c, if you write a function like

```
void func(int arr[100]);
```

The argument `arr` is actually a pointer instead of an array. That is, the following lines are no different.

```
void func(int *arr);
void func(int arr[]);
void func(int arr[100]);
```

So, when you try to `sizeof` the `arr`, you simply get the size of a pointer to `int`. What you get is `sizeof(int *)`.

If a function wants to receive an array, the length of the array have to be given as an argument:

```
void func(int arr[], size_t length);
```

The function for copying array of `Record` should be

```
void copy_array(Record dest[], Record from[], size_t length)
{
    memcpy(dest, from, sizeof(Record) * length);
}
```

Your code can't compile because you mess up the concept of **pointer** and **pointer to array**. 
In your code, `Record (*copy_to)[MAX_RECORDS]`, `copy_to` is a pointer to array of `Record`s. And the length of the pointed array is fixed (MAX_RECORDS).

What's more, the in-place sort of large objects is rather slow. You should consider creating an array of pointers (or indexes) and sort the pointers.

Terribly sorry for broken English.

Comment: `Record (*copy_to)[MAX_RECORDS]` is a pointer, not an array. The copy function is fine apart from the order of memcpy arguments. The array size does not get lost, the function can see the size. He does not have code like any of your `func`s.

Answer (score -2):

Modify your code like below.

```
void copy_record(Record (*copy_to), Record (*copy_from))
{
    memcpy(copy_from, copy_to, sizeof(*copy_from) * MAX_RECORDS);
}

Record* sort_by_title()
{
    Record ret[MAX_RECORDS];
    copy_record(ret, record_inventory); 
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: That would only copy a single record, and you return a dangling pointer